# Why do i get this Java error?

Tags: bluej

in line 3 it says "Cannot find symbol - class ArrayList"  and it highlights the word "ArrayList".
What do i need to do in order to prevent his error from occuring?

Any answers would be highly appreciated.

PLEASE HELPPPP

---

```
public class JobQueue
{
    private ArrayList<Job>myJob;
    private ArrayList<Job>myFinishedJobs;
    private int myJobDuration; 
    private int myTotalDuration;
    /**
     *
     */
     public JobQueue()
    {
      myJob = new ArrayList<Job>();
      myFinishedJobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
      myJobDuration =0; 
      myTotalDuration=0; 
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
     public ArrayList<Job> getPendingJobs()
     {
      return myJob;  
     }

    /**
     * 
     */
     public ArrayList<Job> getCometedJobs()
     {
      return myFinishedJobs;
     } 

    /**
     * 
     */
     public Job getCurrentJob()
     {
       if(myJob!=null)
       { 
        Job FirstJobInTheQueue = myJob.get(0);   
        return FirstJobInTheQueue;
       }
       else
       {
        return null; 
       }
     } 

    /**
     * 
     */
     public int getClockTime()
     {
       return myTotalDuration; 
     }

    /**
     * 
     */

     public int getTotalDuration()
     {
       int totalDuration = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i<myJob.size();i++)
       {
         totalDuration = totalDuration + myJobDuration;
       }
       return totalDuration;
     }

    /**
     * 
     */ 
     public void addJob(Job job)
     {   
        if(job!=null)
        {
          myJob.add(job);
        }
     }

    /**
      * 
      */
     public void addTime(int seconds)
     {
        if(seconds>0)
        {
          myTotalDuration = myTotalDuration + seconds;
        }
     }

    /**
      * 
      * 
      */
     public boolean runAJob()
      {

      } 

    /**
      * 
      */
    public void runAll()
     {

           }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import ArrayList at the top.

`import java.util.ArrayList;`

But you should also make sure you have spaces between the variable type and the variable name.

```
private ArrayList<Job> myJob; 
private ArrayList<Job> myFinishedJobs;
```

Comment: how could i create a method to do this because i have been stuck on this for days......................................................................................................................................runOne() which runs the first job on the queue if there is enough time on the clock.................................................................
runAll() which runs all the jobs on the queue in order until it runs out of time.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding my statement; you have `private ArrayList<Job>myJob;` which is wrong, you need a space between the object type and the variable name.  `private ArrayList<Job> myJob;`

Comment: oh yes sorry i did that but it was easier to reply and not post another set of code.  but did you know how to do the last two? thanks

Comment: no more errors i did what you said for the import i forgot that.   i have to do......................................................................runOne() which runs the first job on the queue if there is enough time on the clock.
runAll() which runs all the jobs on the queue in order until it runs out of tim.................................this is all i have................................................................./**
      * 
      * 
      */
     public boolean runAJob()
      {
        
      } 
    
    /**
      * 
      */
    public void runAll()
     {
      
           }

Comment: The idea in runAJob() should be to pop from your ArrayList treating it as a queue; you should then decrement the time remaining with the time the job took.  For runAll() you should take a peek into the queue to see how long the next job will take to see if it's longer than the time you have left.

Comment: no ideas still...is there anyone here smart enough and knows what the code is? thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

The first line you need to get access to a library class in java via an import statement:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

This makes the `ArrayList` class from the `java.util` package available to our class definition. The `import` statement must always be placed before the class definition in a file.